# Запись данных на диск в 15 раз медленнее отправки по сети?

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, оптимизация, highload

На github есть такая [таблица](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), от разработчика из Microsoft. 
Где-то читал, что запись данных на диск в 15 раз медленнее отправки по сети, это правда? А как же скорость передачи данных по сети? Или типы дисков (SSD и т.д.) ?

Если это так, то получается при разработке веб-проектов, можно оптимизировать отделив БД от основного сервера (БД убрать на отдельный сервер) и делать запросы на добавление/чтение через rest api или по протоколу tcp ?

Что думаете?

Comment: что оптимизировать?)

Comment: В таблице - задержки, а не скорость

Comment: Вы считаете что убрав бд на отдельный сервер вы избежите записи данных на диск или чтение с диска?

Comment: Это может правда, но это лукавство, т.к. практически никто не пишет на диск напрямую, все используют кэширование

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ну так кеширование будет вне зависимости от того где БД. Так что все верно, если будет обращение в кеш то оно быстрее отработает без сети. А если в кеше данных нет, то сеть опять же доп задержки по пути к диску

Answer (score 4):

> то получается при разработке веб-проектов, можно оптимизировать отделив БД от основного сервера (БД убрать на отдельный сервер)

Было: задержка при записи на диск.
Стало: задержка при передаче по сети + задержка при записи на диск.

Отличный способ оптимизации, я считаю.

> Что думаете?

Мы думаем, что лошадь надо запрягать впереди телеги, а не сзади. Любая оптимизация должна идти от проблемы, а не от решения.

**Пока нет конкретной проблемы с производительностью, оптимизировать ничего не нужно.**

Comment: Я вопрос некорректно поставил. 
Например при обработке большого файла с данными, который нужно импортировать в БД. Где скорость обработки (загрузки) данных играет большую роль. 

Мне не важно, насколько быстро они загрузятся в БД, но мне важно, насколько быстро будет обработан файл для импорта. 

В этом случае можно делать отправку по сети по протоколу UDP/TCP, а не напрямую записать в БД ? Это ускорит обработку? 

Или я что-то неправильно понял? 

Вот источник, откуда прочитал информацию: https://habr.com/ru/post/326880/
заголовок: «Гарантированная» доставка сообщений

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf так с импортом в БД получается то же самое: задержка при передаче (данных из файла) по сети + задержка при записи (импортированных в БД данных) на диск. При использовании сети диск никуда не пропадает магическим образом

Comment: @andreymal я же написал, что скорость записи на диск не важен. 
Следовательно, хочу понять, задержки при записи на диск или при передачи по сети сильнее (понятное дело, что тут кучу факторов играет играет роли, начиная от интернет связи, до производительности диска и процессора) - если брать общий случай? 

Тогда о чем  имелось ввиду в статье в пункте «Гарантированная» доставка сообщений ?

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf вот - это уже конкретный вопрос. Но он опять поставлен неправильно. при чем здесь "скорость обработки файла" без учета записи в БД? Какой в этом смысл? Вам надо, наверное, чтобы не файл был быстро обработан, а чтобы быстро отобразилась страница на сайте? ну так это называется отложенная обработка, и городить еще один сервер для этого не обязательно. Сейчас все компьютеры многозадачные, можно вполне поставить задачу обработки файла в фоновый режим, а сайт продолжит работать с пользователем.

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf в статье рассматриваются не БД, а очереди задач. Во-первых, задач может быть десятки тысяч в секунду (на больших сайтах), и обрабатывать их надо максимально быстро. Во-вторых, после успешного выполнения задачи её можно удалить, так что нет необходимости запоминать её на диске. Следовательно, очереди задач возможно ускорить, отказавшись от записи задач на диск. Вы точно так же можете сильно ускорить свою БД, переместив её целиком в оперативную память и отказавшись от диска. Только вот зачем вам БД, которая при перезагрузке сервера потеряет все свои данные?